# Nagios alert integration with external tool

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

I'm integrating alerts and events from Nagios to my system. On searching I have found an integration of Moogsoft with Nagios([click](https://docs.moogsoft.com/display/050108/Nagios+Solution+Pak)). I have followed this, but it was not successful.

In their 'Step 2: Configurations:' they mentioned about 'HOSTNAME',
'BASIC_AUTH' etc. I can't found any of these keys in the respective downloaded file. Can anyone provide clarification or suggest any other solution? Any help would be greatful.

Comment: Do you have to add the configurations yourself? Are they XML format and provide examples on their instructions?

Comment: There is no xml configurations. I followed the steps in the link I have provided above.

Comment: check my answer I think I've found something to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is bad documentation.

Both scripts simply echo (slightly formatted) output from Nagios and pipe this to the 'nc' command with the destination host and port number.  The 'nc' command does not support HTTP authentication (like for instance 'curl' does), so it makes no sense why those options would be documented.  Also, none of the HOSTNAME -to- BASIC_AUTH_PASS variables are ever used in the two shell scripts.

- Set **recStation** to the 'hostname' OR 'ip address' of the Moogsoft server.
- Set **recPort** to the port number the Moogsoft server is listening on.

For example:

```
recStation="192.168.0.199"
recPort="9000"
```

And give it a shot.

Note that IF your Moogsoft system does require HTTP authentication, these scripts simply will not work.  But it would be a simple matter to create a new shell script that used something like 'curl' to add authentication support.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this link](https://docs.moogsoft.com/display/060100/Nagios+LAM) I found.

By the looks of it, you set the variables in the `send-host-event.sh` and `send-service-event.sh` files in the following way:

`<FIELD>=<value>`

So I assume you can place the variables directly after the `recStation` and `recPort` declarations.

**Try this (change the values between the "<>"):**

```
# Host name, IP and Port should match those set for recStation
HOSTNAME="<hostname/ipaddress:9000>"
BASIC_AUTH=<false/true>
# Only need to set these variables if BASIC_AUTH is set to true
BASIC_AUTH_USER="<auth_username>"
BASIC_AUTH_PASS="<auth_password>"
```

I hope that helps?